# Batch Sql Inserter In wifi unestable connection suggestions

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, insert

I have a code in Java for insert many sql lines in database from a text file.
I have the connection programmed with setAutoCommit(false), then at the end if none error happen (detected having all methods throws Throwable), I send the commit.
The task normally take 30 minutes.

It works very good in cable connection, but in a wifi connection it never reach the end because the connection is lost sometimes, for a short time.

For solve it. I programmed two things: The lines of the text file is converted to a serialized object that have all the lines in a ArrayList, and I created other serialized object that have a int index, that save the index of the last line inserted succesfully.

Then, in the program I do this:

```
charge in memory the object.lines, from the serialized object.
charge in memory the object.index, from the serialized object.
```

pseudo code:

```
loop:
index = sum 1 to the object.index
line = object.getLine(index)
insert line
if error continue (or goto loop)
send commit
if error continue (or goto loop)
object.index = index
serialize object
```

in this way I have a backup of the lines that are succesfully commited to the database, and I can continue the job in other time. If I have a connection problem in a line, I can try insert again the line.

If i have a connection problem, i wait 1 minute. The connection is recovered but is reseted automatically, not by me.

Then for example in a lines like this:

```
INSERT INTO my_table1 (id) VALUES (sq_mytable1_id.NEXTVAL);
//success

//connection lost
//connection reset

INSERT INTO my_table2 (id) VALUES (sq_mytable1_id.CURRVAL);
//error, sq_mytable1_id.CURRVAL is not in session.
```

I get a  ORA-08002 exception because, the connection was reset, I can get the sq_mytable1_id.CURRVAL from the session.

Please, you can give me ideas of how programm a batch sql inserter tolerant to connection downs in wi-fi ?

I think serialize the connection, but I cannot: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection is not serializable.

Comment: Why would serialising the connection help? The problem is having two related inserts that look like they should form part of an atomic transaction, treated as two transactions. Essentially you shouldn't commit until after the second insert, though perhaps the transaction should be even larger. You could have a procedure that performs both inserts if that's easier for your logic. You could also return the sequence value as part of the insert, and use that rather than `currval`, but that doesn't sound like the best solution. Are there other constraints that have led you to this scheme?

Comment: I not know how jdbc works internally, but the idea, is keep the same session identifier after a connection reset.

Comment: If you have a new connection then you have a new session, so you won't have the same session ID on the database end; though not quite sure what that has to do with your sequence. If you need to know the sequence value across a connection reset you'll need to retrieve and store it on the Java side and use that in subsequent calls. You cannot make `currval` work across a session change. You also don't seem to be doing anything as a 'batch', these look like lots of single-row inserts. Have you looked at [something like this](http://betteratoracle.com/posts/25-array-batch-inserts-with-jdbc)?